# Parsing cssnext to JSON

Tags: javascript, css, json, node.js, cssnext

I have a cssnext file containing global colours, example:

```
// ../properties.css
:root{
  --colourOne:#000000
  --colourTwo:#000001
}
```

I wish to parse these to a JSON object so that editing the colours may automatically update the styleguide where applicable.

Is it possible to parse this/how do I do it?

Found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonify-css but it doesn't seem to be installing for me.

Other technologies being used:

- React
- Styleguidist
- Webpack

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the cssjson-cli library:

```
> npm install -g cssjson-cli
> cssjson style.css --output style.js
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using cssjson but **not the cli**, as this would be more like what I wanted. Unfortunately (I think due to the CSS format) it responds with empty objects.